# Data not getting created in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have set a association between two models

Question.rb

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  field :right_answer, type: String
  has_many :choices
end
```

Choice.rb

```
class Choice
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :option, type: String
  belongs_to :question
end
```

And then I am trying to create a choice  object doing

```
Choice.create(option: "xxxxx")
```

When I check the db doing Choice.last , I cant't see the last created object. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: try this `belongs_to :question, optional: true`, restart and reload : server and console

Comment: thats why `optional: true` allows to ignore the question id requirement.

Comment: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html#opting-out-of-this-default-behavior-in-rails-5

Answer (score 0):

folowing mongoDB documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-documents/)
seems that you miss the line tho set db and collection where save model.

The folowing example code is picked up from official documentation:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.singular("status", "status")
end
```